# How to test datepicker with capybara

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xpath, datepicker, capybara

anyone know how to create a callback on html input's value change, or someone know how to test clicking on jquery ui datepicker and timepicker? I have tried, onchange does not work == , the value I'm talking about is the value HTML attribute of the input element, and the element is a readonly element. I'm facing this problem because I'm setting the value of the element for capybara testing with execute script running jQuery and the date input is a react component, datepicker function mounted on to the element on oncomponentdidmounted callback, with datepicker function's onSelect callback changing the state of the page. I have tried to use xpath to click but that also does not work accordingly. I have tried page.execute_script aswell but it does not help.

```
page.execute_script("$($('.start-datepicker.hasDatepicker')[0]).val('23/11/2016');")
page.execute_script("$($('.start-timepicker.hasTimepicker')[0]).val('07:25 AM');")
page.execute_script("$($('.end-datepicker.hasDatepicker')[0]).val('24/11/2016');")
page.execute_script("$($('.end-timepicker.hasTimepicker')[0]).val('08:25 AM');")
```

[image]

I have more than 1 date picker on one page.

Comment: do you want to read or set the value?